# Animation using jquery , a swf file to jquery animation

Tags: jquery

I have a flash file 
http://www.levoirsolutions.com/test.swf

I want to implement this animation using jquery, is it possible?
Can anybody help me do that ?

Comment: As it stands, this question is a textbook non-constructive one. You should provide all relevant information in the description of the question. Read more: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/213383)

Answer (score 1):

Use an animated GIF, it looks pretty simple.  No sense in doing it with JavaScript, or Flash for that matter.